# Loading an application inside the container of another application

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I am trying load application inside a container of another application in Android. Need sample code on how to do the process since I am new to Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is nearly impossible unless your device is rooted. The applications can only interact with other applications is via Intents but in this case it will not happen. Long story short, I would recommend you not to load another application in a 'View' as this is almost impossible. 
The only thing I would recommend you to do is to revisit your requirement and amend them to accommodate you to launch another application from your application. For this, you'll have to make two separate applications. The code for this is the following:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
    //null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

If for whatever reason you need to implement the original way, I would personally start studying Fragments to achieve that type of functionality.